# Is there an alternate spelling of \n in javascript?

Tags: javascript, newline, unicode-escapes, tumblr-themes

Due to a bug in the Tumblr theme editor, any time the sequence `\n` appears in the source code, it is converted to an actual line break in the source code itself. Therefore, putting the `\n` sequence into a Javascript string causes the program to crash, as it breaks the string into multiple lines.

I was wondering if there is another way to notate the newline character in JavaScript, which could allow me to work around this issue.

Comment: Sometimes with cases like this I try a double backslash like: `\\n` as a first workaround.  I don't know if it will help or not in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow, that's an ugly bug.

Yes, you can use `\u000a` instead (or `\u000A`). It's the Unicode escape sequence for the same character. (Or worse case: `String.fromCharCode(10)`.)

Gratuitous example:

```js
console.log("\n" === "\u000a");                // true
console.log("\n" === "\u000A");                // true
console.log("\n" === String.fromCharCode(10)); // true
```

Comment: looks like I had to use the String.fromCharCode(10). Very ugly, but it works perfectly. I will definitely leave an explanatory note to future developers. Thanks again :)